# .Net Core how to create views for relations

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

Hi I modelled a simple many to many with this way

```
   public class Book
    {
      
        public int Id { get; set; }
       
        public string BookName { get; set; }
        public string ISBN { get; set; }

        public IList<BookAuthor> BookAuthor { get; set; }

    }

 public class Author
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string AuthorName { get; set; }

        public IList<BookAuthor> BookAuthor { get; set; }

    }



public class BookAuthor
    {
        public int BookId { get; set; }
        public Book Book { get; set; }

        public int AuthorId { get; set; }
        public Author Author { get; set; }
    }
```

And also in context

```
  public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }
        public DbSet<BookAuthor> BookAuthor { get; set; }
```

It created 3 table in db with one bridge table. I just want to create views for many to many relations.
In my story a book can have many author. A author can have many book.

I created a ef controller with views for Book and Author model it only created view with one input area
Also I created ef controller for bridgemodel(BookAuthor) it creates view with 2 dropdown button with only ids
How can I create view for it.
Thank you

Comment: I just want to make a crud page for 2 related entity

Answer (score 1):

> how to create views for relations

First, in the controller, you should use `Include` and `ThenInclude` method to load the related entity from the database, code like this:

```
 _dbcontext.Books.Include(c => c.BookAuthor).ThenInclude(c => c.Author);
```

Then, return the query result to the View page. In the View Page, you could use `foreach` statement to loop through the BookAuthor list and get the related entity, like this:

```
    @model IEnumerable<WebApplication2.Models.Book>

    @{
        ViewData["Title"] = "BookIndex";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }

    <h1>BookIndex</h1>

    <p>
        <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
    </p>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BookName)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ISBN)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BookAuthor)
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BookName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ISBN)
                </td>
                <td>
                   @{ var authorlist = new List<string>();
                       foreach (var author in item.BookAuthor)
                       {
                           authorlist.Add(author.Author.AuthorName);
                       }
                       @string.Join(",", authorlist);
                   }
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
                </td>
            </tr>
    }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

The Index page like this:

[image]

Here are some related articles, you could check them:

[Read related data - ASP.NET MVC with EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/read-related-data?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

[Update related data - ASP.NET MVC with EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/update-related-data?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

The following code is used to insert Book with author, you could also refer to them:

Create a BookViewModel to add book name and author name:

```
public class BookViewModel
{
    public string BookName { get; set; }
    public string ISBN { get; set; }

    public string AuthorName { get; set; } //if add multiple author, using "," separate them.
}
```

code in the View page:

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.BookViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "AddBook";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>AddBook</h1>

<h4>BookViewModel</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="AddBook">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="BookName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="BookName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="BookName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ISBN" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ISBN" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ISBN" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="AuthorName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="AuthorName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="AuthorName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code in the controller:

```
    public IActionResult AddBook()
    {

        return View();                 
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult AddBook(BookViewModel bookViewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var newbook = new Book() { BookName = bookViewModel.BookName, ISBN = bookViewModel.ISBN};

            string[] author = bookViewModel.AuthorName.Split(','); //if have multiple author, using "," separate them.
            //List<Author> authors = new List<Author>();
            List<BookAuthor> bookAuthors = new List<BookAuthor>();
            List<Author> newauthors = new List<Author>();
            foreach (var item in author)
            {
               var existauthor = _dbcontext.Authors.Where(c => c.AuthorName.ToLower() == item.ToLower()).FirstOrDefault();
                if (existauthor == null)
                {
                    existauthor = new Author() { AuthorName = item };
                    newauthors.Add(existauthor);
                }
                //authors.Add(existauthor);
                bookAuthors.Add(new BookAuthor() { Author = existauthor, Book = newbook });
            }

            _dbcontext.Authors.AddRange(newauthors);
            _dbcontext.Books.AddRange(newbook);
            _dbcontext.BookAuthors.AddRange(bookAuthors);

            _dbcontext.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(BookIndex));
        }
        return View();
    }
```